# Transfering file on UDP socket in C! Linux

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I'm programming an application for transferring a file between two host with an UDP socket.

But it seems that some data arrives corrupted at the client.

My question is: is it possible that if the server is faster than the client, the client could read corrupted data from the socket?

I use `sendto()` in the server and `read()` in the client (I use the `connect()` before beginning transferring the file in the client),
and if yes: how can I stop the server from sending new data until the client has read all the previous data?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The UDP protocol does not guarantee that the packet will be seen by the receiver NOR does it guarantee that the packets will be received in the correct order.   Strongly suggest using TCP protocol as that does make those guarantees

Comment: To transfer files reliably over UDP you will need to implement some protocol by which the receiver can detect when the incoming packets have been dropped or received out of sequence (e.g. by putting a sequence-ID field into each packet) and then request that the sender resend the dropped packet(s).  To be robust, it should also deal with the possibility that its resend-request packets get dropped, and so on.  (As @user3629249 mentions, it's much easier to use TCP if you have a  choice, since all those details will get handled for you by the TCP layer)

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible that if the server is faster than the client, the
>   client could read corrupted data from the socket?

No it is not possible - every datagram that you see is error checked by the IP layer and will be as it was sent.

> how can I stop the server from sending new data until the client has
>   read all the previous data?

Typically you send a small packet, the receiver sends an acknowledgement, then you send the next. Problem with UDP however is packets can get dropped without telling you event duplicated moreover you can flood the network as there is no congestion control..

So why re-invent the wheel, **use TCP** for sending files which takes care of reliability and congestion control - everyone has been using that for decades, e.g. this web page is delivered to you using HTTP which uses TCP.